# Connecting WSO2 EI to Denodo - Simple Query

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, denodo, wso2-esb

I am trying to connect to a Denodo Data source from WSO2 EI using PostgreSQL DB parameters.

I am able to fetch the details using simple queries.

However when I add a simple  "*where*" condition I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received resultset tuples, but no field structure for them
```

I am using the following driver downloaded from postgresql website :

**postgresql-42.1.3.jar**

Note : The postgresql JDBC drivers from Denodo package doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Does WSO2 let you use your own JDBC driver?

If I recall, you should use the Denodo JDBC driver, not the postgresql driver.

See https://community.denodo.com/kb/view/document/Connection%20using%20third%20party%20SQL%20clients?tag=JDBC+driver

Comment: Hello @Colorado Techie Thank you for your answer. I placed the postgresql driver in the wso2 lib folder. In that way i was able to query the data but not with the where condition. I did indeed try the Denodo driver as well which gave me an error like a secure connection failure.

Comment: When I do a test connection with the Denodo driver, i get the following message :                                                                                                   Caused by: *java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader.testDataSourceConnection(RDBMSDataSourceReader.java:80)*